# Launching a process from dmenu blocks XMonad

Tags: haskell, xmonad, dmenu

I have an issue with a function I took from [XMonad.Util.Dmenu](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Util-Dmenu.html), namely dmenuXinerama (see below). It seems like this is happening:

> These functions block xmonad's event loop until dmenu exits; this
> means that programs will not be able to open new windows and you will
> not be able to change workspaces or input focus until you have
> responded to the prompt one way or another.

What happens is that I spawn a menu instance and it appears, but once I run something from there, everything is blocked, and I can't do anything.

This is the function:

```
dmenuXinerama :: [String] -> X String
dmenuXinerama opts = do
    curscreen <- (fromIntegral . W.screen . W.current) `fmap` gets windowset :: X Int
    io $ runProcessWithInput "dmenu_run" ["-m", show curscreen] (unlines opts)
```

... and a binding:

```
-- Spawn dmenu
, ((modMask, xK_p), void $ dmenuXinerama [])
```

I've also tried this:

```
dmenuXinerama :: [String] -> X String
dmenuXinerama opts = do
    curscreen <-
      (fromIntegral . W.screen . W.current) `fmap` gets windowset :: X Int
    _ <-
      runProcessWithInput "dmenu_run" ["-m", show curscreen] (unlines opts)
    menuArgs "dmenu_run" ["-m", show curscreen] opts

-- | Like 'menu' but also takes a list of command line arguments.
menuArgs :: MonadIO m => String -> [String] -> [String] -> m String
menuArgs menuCmd args opts = liftM (filter (/='\n')) $
  runProcessWithInput menuCmd args (unlines opts)
```

I'd appreciate it if someone explained what's going on and how can I overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `dmenu_run` doesn't exit (until the program you start with it does), so it is not suitable for use with `runProcessWithInput`. Use `dmenu_path` and `dmenu` instead, then `spawn` the result.

```
pickExe :: X ()
pickExe = do
    exes <- runProcessWithInput "dmenu_path" [] ""
    exe <- dmenuXinerama (lines exes)
    spawn exe
```

The `dmenuXinerama` in the above snippet is the one you can import from `XMonad.Util.Dmenu`, not your modified one from the question. (And `spawn` is from `XMonad.Core`.)

If you are comfortable with the `Monad` interface, you might prefer to write that without the temporary names like this:

```
pickExe = spawn =<< dmenuXinerama . lines =<< runProcessWithInput "dmenu_path" [] ""
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I see that the `XMonad.Util.Dmenu` module uses `-xs`, and there are no `-x` and `-s` options in my `dmenu`, which is a reason why I defined my own function in the first place. The second reason was that dmenu gets spawned on the wrong screen because that `+1` in the code. If I remove that, it gets spawned on the right screen. When it comes to your snippets, I have tried them, and the first snippet wouldn't work, I had to wrap `exes` in a list (`[exes]`), and once it compiled, `dmenu` was not getting spawned at all.

Comment: As for your second snippet, I get an error, too, saying `Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’  Expected type: String -> X String Actual type: [String] -> X String`, that's a red squiggly line under `dmenuXinerama` in my editor. I'd appreciate suggestions as to how to make the function I defined work correctly, because my dmenu hasn't got those options, and it gets spawned on the wrong screen. dmenu version is `dmenu-4.8`.

Comment: Seems like I got it to work with combination of my function and your thing.

Comment: @adder As discussed in the documentation, the `-xs` used by `dmenuXinerama` requires that you apply jcreigh's multi-monitor patch to dmenu. (You *did* read the documentation, right?) Apologies about the `String`/`[String]` bit. I was a bit sloppy. The correct way is `dmenuXinerama (lines exes)` (or `dmenu (lines exes)` if you don't want to use `dmenuXinerama`). The analogous fix to the second version is `spawn =<< dmenuXinerama . lines =<< runProcessWithInput "dmenu_path" [] ""`.